# Can I really persist data on disk using couchbase

Tags: couchbase

I have a lot of data needed to stored on disk.
Since it is only key-value pairs, I want to use couchbase to do it.

The data is several GB and I only allocate 1 GB RAM to the bucket.
I though RAM to couchbase is only a cache. 
But after inserting a lot of data I got:

```
Hard Out Of Memory Error. Bucket "test2" on node 100.66.32.169 is full. All memory allocated to this bucket is used for metadata.
```

when I open the couchbase web console.

Can couchbase be a database to store data on disk? Or it is RAM oritented?

Update:

OK, let me make the question more specific:
In couchbase:

1. If I allocate the RAM of a bucket to be 1 GB, can I store 10 GB data to that bucket?
2. If I can do 1. , can I consider that 1 GB RAM is a kind of cache of the 10 GB data (just like CPU L2 cache is a cache of RAM) ?

Comment: 1. Yes
2. 1GB would be allocated to the built in managed cache in Couchbase for that bucket. Couchbase's data service is a layer consolidation of a managed cache and persistence layer to make up the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, Couchbase stores all keys (and some metadata) in RAM, and fills whatever remains with values. Starting with version 3.0, you can set your bucket to full-eviction mode, which only keeps the keys of cached documents in RAM. This lets you store much more data than you have memory, but at a cost to performance to some read operations, especially trying to retrieve keys that don't exist.

To solve your specific problem, edit the bucket and set it to full metadata eviction. Note that this will restart the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

Couchbase tries to keep as much of the "live dataset" (ie. most used / requested keys) into the node's memory. This is key to the performance of the database, and part of the design, so good memory sizing of your nodes and quotas of your buckets are key.

It does offer persistence, but I'd say this is not a disk-first oriented database.

Persistence to disk is mainly for two things: making data durable and resilient to node shutdown (of course) and off-load data (in priority least used data) from RAM to disk.

Comment: Can I consider RAM in couchbase is a kind of cache?

Comment: that's the spirit, yeah... see David Ostrovsky answer to your updated question ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking a bunch of different questions here.
Specifically about the error message: looks like your bucket is simply too small to hold all the data you're storing in it.

About persisting to disc: you *can* force couchbase to write to disc (and even configure the number of nodes that docs are replicated into) but as noted above, that would probably hurt your performance a little.

Have a look, for example, at the persist_to flag in the set() api of the python client for couchbase.

[couchbase client for python](http://www.couchbase.com/autodocs/couchbase-python-client-1.2.0/html/api/couchbase.html)